# Как правильно читать из InputStream?

Tags: java, сокет

Java программа стоит proxy-сервером на 8080 порту для протокола HTTP.
`socket` - это объект возвращаемый `ServerSocket.accept()`
Проблема в том, что прочитав переданные браузером данные код зависает на is.read(buf), то есть ожидает новых данных, но их нет, потому что браузер просто ждет ответа от proxy.
Как я понимаю- я либо неправильно читаю из `InputStream`, либо мне нужно получив два переноса строк (конец блока данных GET запроса) начинать обрабатывать запрос, не пытаясь снова читать из `InputStream`.
Что из этого верно?

```
String res="";
InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
byte[] buf=new byte[512];
int size;
while ((size=is.read(buf))>0){ // в соответствии с документацией вернет -1 при окончании данных, но здесь происходит зависание
    res+=new String(buf).substring(0, size);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы чтение из сокета было неблокирующим, надо перед чтением проверять `InputStream.available()`, иначе можно до покровов ждать...

Comment: Спасибо
[]()

Answer (score 0):

есть одно но:
The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.